# How can I add widgets to an existing screen?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

my application is built from a .kv file.

I want to add buttons to a `Screen` from my python file.

```
class Profiles(Screen):
    def suh(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.add_widget(Button(text=i))
```

The `suh` function seem to have no effect. Is this because the function is called after the app is built? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are trying to add multiple widgets to a screen. What you mean to be doing is add multiple widgets to a `Layout` object (like `FloatLayout`, `GridLayout`, or `BoxLayout`) and add that layout to your screen. Screens can only have 1 child widget.

Comment: @Erik ah, that makes sense. So I created a `GridLayout` named `pro` in the `Profiles` `Screen` within the .kv file. On my .py file, instead of `self.add_widget(Button)` I have `root.ids["pro"].add_widget(Button)` , but root is not defined. why? T_T

Comment: if you have an id of `pro` in your `Profiles` class, you need to reference it by `self.ids['pro']` rather than `root.ids`. `self.root` refers to the highest level widget in the tree that `self` is in. `root` is simply an undefined variable at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

Since Screen is a *RelativeLayout*, use `on_pre_enter` or `on_enter` to inovke method, *suh()*, plus add `size` and `pos` to Button widget.

## Solution 2

Use a container e.g. *BoxLayout* or *Gridayout* on top of Screen.

## *Note*

Whenever widget is added to a screen via `on_pre_enter` or `on_enter`, use `on_pre_leave` or `on_leave` to remove the widget. This is to prevent doubling your widget each time the screen is entered.

If the widgets are cleared too fast, use *[Clock.schedule_once](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)* with a time interval.

## Note 1: Screen Events

Kivy Screen has the following events.

[Kivy Screen » Events](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen)

> *on_pre_enter: ()*
>
> Event fired when the screen is about to be used: the entering
>   animation is started.
>
> *on_enter: ()*
>
> Event fired when the screen is displayed: the entering animation is
>   complete.
>
> *on_pre_leave: ()*
>
> Event fired when the screen is about to be removed: the leaving
>   animation is started.
>
> *on_leave: ()*
>
> Event fired when the screen is removed: the leaving animation is
>   finished.

## Note 2: Screen is a RelativeLayout

[Kivy Screen » RelativeLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html)

> Please note that by default, a [Screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) displays nothing: it’s just
>   a [RelativeLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#kivy.uix.relativelayout.RelativeLayout). You need to use that class as a root widget for
>   your own screen, the best way being to subclass.
>
> Warning
>
> As [Screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) is a [RelativeLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#kivy.uix.relativelayout.RelativeLayout), it is important to understand
>   the [Common Pitfalls](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#kivy-uix-relativelayout-common-pitfalls).

## Example - Solution 1

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Profiles>:
    # on_pre_enter: self.suh()
    on_enter: self.suh()
""")


class Profiles(Screen):
    def suh(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i), size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), pos=(i*100, i*100)))


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Profiles(name='profiles'))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output - Solution 1

[image: Output - Solution 1]

## Example - Solution 2

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Profiles>:
    # on_pre_enter: self.suh()
    on_enter: self.suh()
    BoxLayout:
        id: container
""")


class Profiles(Screen):
    def suh(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.ids.container.add_widget(Button(text=str(i), size_hint=(0.1, 0.1)))


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Profiles(name='profiles'))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output - Solution 2

[image: Output - Solution 2]

Comment: Note 1 and your answer overall was super useful. Thank you!

Comment: lets say i wanted to only create the buttons only once. would I have to create a function that clears the widgets of `containter` and link it to `on_leave`, or is there a better way of doing this? if I use `on_leave` and switch between screens quickly, the clear widget function doesn't execute. and when I use `on_pre_leave`, it clears the widgets too quick, thus giving it a bad screen transition.

Comment: Whenever widget is added to a screen via *on_pre_enter* or *on_enter*, use *on_pre_leave* or *on_leave* to remove the widget. This is to prevent doubling your widget each time the screen is entered. If the widgets are cleared too fast, use *Clock.schedule_once* with a time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Add the widgets through the `App` class in stead of the `Screen`.  So you would have to create a function that creates the widgets, and in your build function, you would have to use `Clock.schedule_once` from the `Clock` module to run the other function. Example:

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.yoyo, 0)
        return MainWin()

    def yoyo(self, *args):
        for i in memu_acc:
            self.root.ids["prof"].ids["pro"].add_widget(Button(text=i))
```